# Separate domain names and urls

Tags: url, dns, cross-domain

I am trying to separte the domain name from url. But I am confused if i should consider it domain name or not.

http://en.wikipedia.org/

is it considered a domain name with or URL ?

Answer (score 0):

You posted the URL `http://en.wikipedia.org/` which contains the domain name `en.wikipedia.org`.

A [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) is a DNS identifier consisting of hostname and domain, like this one:

> `en.wikipedia.org.`

A HTTP [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) however, also provides among other things a *scheme* (the protocol in your case) and a *path*, which is simply `/` (the mandatory beginning) in your case:

> `http://en.wikipedia.org/`

What do you mean by “separate”? Were you curious about the abstract concept, or do you want to actually separate the strings respectively?